# Не получается подключить картинку в Wordpress (на Woocommerce single product page), путь прописан правильно

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пишу себе плагин для расчета индивидуальных штор. Не могу понять, почему не получается подключить картинку. Путь прописан правильно. Все перепробовала.

```
function mabou_step_two(){
echo'<div class="mabou_shtory_calc_step_two_title" id="mabou_step_one_title"><span><a>ШАГ 2</a></span></div>';
echo'<div class="mabou_step_two" id="mabou_step_two">';

 $img_src=plugins_url( 'imgs/shtornaya_lenta_small.png',__FILE__);
 echo '<div class="shtornaya_lenta" id="shtorn_lenta"><span><img srс="'.$img_src.'"  alt="shrornaya_lenta"></span></div>';
    echo '</div>';       
}
```

Данную функцию я вызываю в функции `mabou_add_my_fields` - использую хук

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','mabou_add_my_fields');
```

Это принтскрин моего плагина (по ничего не выравнивала):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что возвращает переменная $img_src? напишите var_dump($img_src); после присваивания и посмотрите что в ней вообще хранится.

Comment: string - путь к картинке и он правильно прописан

Comment: Попробуйте убрать второй параметр  __FILE__ . И посмотрите путь через инспектор в браузере т.к. константа __FILE__ не верно показывает через var_dump.

Comment: без __FILE__ не прописывается путь к моему плагину (пишу все локально)

Comment: без файл неправильный путь, по нему нельзя получить картинку

Comment: папка img (и соответственно картинка) находится в моем плагине

Comment: Вы сказали img, а в функции imgs. Еще раз уточню, вы можете открыть инспектор в браузере, выбрать изображение, скопировать у него путь, открыть в др вкладке и оно откроется? Верно?

Comment: Простите, да, папка называется imgs, моя описка

Comment: на счет пути, да

Comment: картинка открывается

Comment: поэтому я и пишу, что путь правильный

Comment: Сложно сказать, мне бы скриншоты консоли браузера и скрин самого элемента в инспекторе. Так же в wp_config.php поставьте define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE );

Comment: прошу прощения за задержку, добавила картинку (см. выше), надеюсь, то))

Comment: Не совсем, нужна вкладка console( следущая) но уже видно что есть 1 ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей, да в консоли ошибка, 404

Comment: Попробую исправить

Comment: Была ошибочка в css, а так все тоже

Comment: Получилось сделать только backround-image для дива

Comment: я сейчас скопировал ваш код, в итоге у вас srс в изображении написано русскими буквами - поэтому не открывается.
https://gyazo.com/c325c6ee6922a01841608f997a7391e3

Comment: Вот блин, тупость какая, тьфу (у меня 4 языка в компе), видимо, недосмотрела. Спасибо Вам большое